# Can I filter out certain tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

When browsing through questions I can set a custom filter to only show me questions with specific tags. Can I also do the opposite? Like say, I want to see all questions except questions which have the `java` tag?

I'm aware of this:

> To exclude results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with - in your query: waffles -unicorns finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while [laurel] -[hardy] includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.

But I don't want to search for something, instead I want to set a filter, so I can see all questions, expect those with certain tags.